# Como montar query em PDO com itens antes concatenados

Tags: php, sql, query, pdo

A dúvida é a seguinte, no mysql podemos concatenar uma query e depois realizar a busca, da seguinte maneira:

```
$cidades = '&& (cidade = 100 || cidade = 101 || cidade = 102)';
$order = 'id ASC';

$sql = 'SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE status = 1 '.$cidades.' ORDER BY '.$order;
```

a variável `$cidade` pode ser vazia ou possuir n elementos para busca, não consigo fazer assim, não sei também se seria dessa forma:

```
$sql = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE status = 1 :cidades ORDER BY :order');

$sql->execute(array(':cidades' => $cidades, ':order' => $order));
```

Comment: `$cidades` é um array ou uma string?

Comment: `$cidades` é uma string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para conseguir realizar essa consulta dinâmica vai, precisar de alguns ajuste, o primeiro é transformar `$cidades` em um array e jogar em um clasula `IN()`, trocar `execute()` por `bindValue()` para fazer o order by funcionar, o bind não pode ser feito com o nome da coluna apenas o indíce.

```
$in = "";

$posicao = 2;
if(!empty($cidades)){
    $cidades = array(100, 101, 102);
    $totalInterrogacoes = count($cidades);
    $interrogacoes = str_repeat('?,', $totalInterrogacoes);
    $interrogacoes = substr($interrogacoes, 0, -1);
    $in = " AND cidades IN($interrogacoes) ";
}   

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE status = ? "
$stmt = $this->_db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(1, 1);

if($in){
    $stmt->bindValue($posicao, implode($cidades));
    $sql .= $in ." ORDER BY ?";
    $posicao++;
}   

$stmt->bindValue($posicao, 1, PDO::PARAM_INT);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Usar o que? @MarcosRegis

Comment: Uma forma mais simples é usar `$in = " AND cidades IN(" . implode(',', $cidades) . ") ";` ao invés de `count + repeat + substr` e verificações posteriores para o bind já que se trata de inteiros.

Comment: @MarcosRegis `$cidades = array(100, 101, 102);echo implode("?,", $cidades);` imprime `100?,101?,102` o certo seria exibir apenas as interrogações. É possível fazer com `array_fill()` mas também não fica tão bom. `$cidades = array(100, 101, 102); echo implode(",", array_fill(0, count($cidades), '?'));`

Comment: Foi falta de intimidade com o teclado :D, mas corrigi o comentário.

Comment: Fiz alguma modificações a partir do exemplo dado, funcionando aqui! obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

O que você pode fazer é colocar todos os ids da cidade em um array caso tenha algum id, faça um implode, senão deixe a variável em branco.

**Exemplo:**

temos os ids das cidades: 26,50 e 20.

```
$cidades =($arrayCidade != '' && count($arrayCidade) > 0) ? "AND (id='". implode("' OR id='", $arrayCidade) . "')" : '';
```

Só usar dentro do PDO a variavel $cidades. Certifique-se que esteja entrando somente numeros dento do array, para não ter o SqlInjection.